# How to get a specific item from Picture Library

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I'd like to get an item(logo) from the picture library we have created for this items. I need to get the item by the logo name and then update a field in that item. I couldn't find a CAML query to look for the Name of the file (picture).

Please, can you tell me how the query for this kind of field is...

Answer (score 0):

If you want the name as in the title of the item you will want to do:

```
  <Where>
    <Eq>
      <FieldRef Name="Title" />
      <Value Type="Text">{Your Item Title Here}</Value>
    </Eq>
  </Where>
```

If you want the name as in the filename of the file you uploaded (ex. mylogo.png) then you will want something like:

```
  <Where>
    <Eq>
      <FieldRef Name="FileLeafRef" />
      <Value Type="Text">{Your File Name with Extension here}</Value>
    </Eq>
  </Where>
```